# Multi class classification Metric Finding argmax along each row of a 2d tensor, and change them to 1 in keras backed K for TP,FP,FN calculation

Tags: python, keras

I am having a multi class classification problem. My keras model giving continuous vectors at the end of prediction.

Here is the code i have in numpy based that i use for evaluation from model.predict.
So, I am trying for TP, FP, FN calculation in keras metric itself which i can get from `keras.evaluate`.

Numpy Snippet Used:

```
#   y_true is one hot of classes.

# Continuos values
y_pred_continuos = model.predict(xfeature)    
# Discrete Values
y_pred = np.zeros_like(y_pred_continuos)
y_pred[np.arange(len(y_pred_continuos)), y_pred_continuos.argmax(1)] = 1   

cur_TP = np.multiply(y_true,y_pred)
cur_FP = y_pred - cur_TP
cur_FN = y_true - cur_TP
cur_TP = cur_TP.sum(axis=0)
cur_FP = cur_FP.sum(axis=0)
cur_FN = cur_FN.sum(axis=0)
```

y_true, and y_pred will be avialble in keras [Custom Metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/).
In Keras, I have tried like:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
cy_true = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])
cy_pred = np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(2,4)

y_true = K.variable(cy_true,)
y_pred = K.variable(cy_pred)
y_pred_discrete = K.zeros_like(y_pred)
```

I am unaware on how to loop over and find one hot of continuos vector.

Also Using scikit-learn's classification report, I can get the same. To do that, I have to run it out of Keras Metrics by saving predictions and then analysis.

But I want them as keras metric to find TP,FP,FN,TN for multi class classfication .

I have written them for multi label classification where I have just sorting of predictions, followed by selecting top k.

But in case of multi class, I dont know how to loop over a keras tensor.

If I find them in Keras Metric itself, then I can write a callback in keras using BaseAccumulator to cumulate the values over batches and at the epoch end, i can get metric F1 too,  Also I cann use to monitor my training process.

Comment: What do u mean by continuous vector? If you mean one hot encoded, then just use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html to get the "tru" value.  E.g  `a=[[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]`   np.argmax(a) will return [2,0]

Comment: I mean Continuous values instead of one hot encoded. 

Ofcourse I am using numpy now but separately instead of inside a Keras Metric.
I want a way to get TP, FP,FN as keras metric, like keras 'accuracy'.

Comment: You can use classification_report from scikit learn or plot confusion matrix using also scikit learn. Just types those word on Google to find corresponding documentations

Comment: I want them in Keras Metric so that the same computation of prediction for a batch in keras epoch during training, wont be repeated. Else the predict part to happen again outside.